# Стоит ли избегать развернутых ответов?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё

Например, я попробовал максимально развернуто ответить на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-python) вопрос. @jfs в комментариях правильно отметил, что вопросов о производительности никто не ставил. Выходит, что "правильным" ответом был бы кусок кода и ссылка на документацию? Предоставляя какие-то рассуждения и углубляясь в тему я руководствовался следующими мыслями: даже стандартными средствами задачу можно решить несколькими способами, как автор должен выбрать подходящий для него? Привел результаты замеров производительности. У самого появился вопрос о том, почему один метод так сильно отличается от другого - привел объяснение почему. И так одно за другим ответ значительно подрос в объеме - и это даже без упоминания решений из сторонних библиотек. Руководствуясь правилом "ничего лишнего" - это ответ на 3 вопроса сразу: 'как', 'что лучше' и 'почему'. Стоит ли дожидаться этих вопросов? Также в ответе целое множество технических тонкостей не затронуто, например, запуск кода не на CPython. Разве приведенные сведения без абсолютно всех подробностей совсем бесполезны? На enSO часто встречаются довольно подробные ответы и сообщество считает их полезными.

Не совсем понятно, когда остановиться, а если не останавливаться, то можно до физики полупроводников добраться. Или может просто сделать ответ общественным, но будет ли его-кто-нибудь улучшать? А может дело в недостаточной для подробных ответов квалификации? Но на этот случай есть сообщество, которое может заминусовать, закрыть, надавать по шапке в комментариях.

Что я делаю не так, стоит ли пытаться отвечать подробно на похожие вопросы, как это делать, каких подробностей избегать?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [На кого рассчитывать ответ?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1872/181472)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Развернутые ответы - это добро. Не стоит их избегать.

Comment: Можно выделить заголовком решение для тех, кто торопится.

Comment: мне кажется уже был такой же вопрос про длинные ответы, в частности VladD, но найти не могу что-то

Comment: @Grundy это? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1872/181100

Comment: @Grundy просто там ответ был слишком длинным и развернутым

Comment: @Кнопкатык, скорее вот: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1944/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Несколько иронично, что в данном случае однострочный ответ так высоко оценен. =)

Answer (score 7):

У меня нет претензий к развёрнутости вашего ответа.

Проблема не в развёрнутости ответа, а в сокрытии правильного ответа и в недостаточном изложении темы, о которой не было прямого вопроса—иначе говоря я бы не стал оставлять комментарии, если бы тема производительности была корректно изложена либо её бы не было в ответе вообще.

Правильный ответ на вопрос, использует `collections.Counter()`, только читая ваш ответ это далеко не очевидно. Лучше следовать обратной информационной пирамиде: самое важное на самом верху ответа должно находится, чтобы можно было остановится при чтении ответа, прочитав самое важное и упустив только детали.

Про производительность: если уж стали отвечать на вопрос, который явно не стоял, то отвечайте как следует. Не обещайте слишком много, когда измеряете: почти невозможно предсказать как себя поведёт система с другим вводом, на другой версии софта или другом железе. [Полезная ссылка](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/why-measure-toy-benchmark-programs.html).