# Правильно ли отвечать на вопрос "энциклопедически"?

Tags: обсуждение

Правильно ли это со стороны отвечающего отвечать на вопрос несколькими методами (так сказать **очень обширно**) или лучше воздерживаться от такого,чтоб не плодить скрипткиди и 'i_cant_google' юзеров ?

Comment: Очень обширно - будет не ответ; тревога -> удалить. Обширно, т. е. все-все аспекты обозреть - в общем и целом можно, но вряд ли кому-то нужна простыня воды (хотя куча примеров больших, но хороших ответов).

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на пример. Сейчас не очень понятно, о чём речь.

Comment: @Skyrocker интересно, какую тревогу вы поставили бы на слишком обширный ответ :)

Comment: @Arhad, ссылки на пример - нет. Но представьте,что отвечающий даёт 10 вариаций решения проблемы.

Comment: `отвечающий даёт 10 вариаций решения проблемы` – если всё раскидано по десяти ответам, ответ на вариацию, – почему бы и нет. А насчёт `i_cant_google` – ну так гугл как правило сюда как раз и отправляет.

Comment: И связанный: [Стоит ли избегать развернутых ответов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/181100)

Comment: Есть люди 'i can't google',а есть такие как я , которые засоряют дубликатами. Facepalm.

Comment: Здесь есть эффективные средства для работы с дубликатами, так что от "засорения дубликатами", вреда практически ноль. Не берите в голову.

Comment: @PashaPash, да любую, кроме спама. Косвенно подходят все.

Comment: @Skyrocker не подходит ни одна. Ни прямо, ни косвенно. Т.е. поставить вы можете, но ее все равно завернут.

Comment: @PashaPash, "невежливый или оскорбительный" -> оскорбительно думать что тебя считают недалёким и разжёвывают по термину. "не является ответом" -> ответ есть, но на уровне "догадайся что тут ответ", что не лучше посыла в гугл. "требуется вмешательство модератора" -> пусть модератор расскажет что так делать не нужно.

Comment: @stackflow вообще-то этот вопрос не совсем дубликат. Тот вопрос о проблеме читабельности длинных ответов, а не об их "образовательной" роли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю, каким образом обширные ответы могут "плодить скрипткиди". Если их что-то и плодит, то это скорее наоборот, ответы с одним кодом без всяких пояснений. Приводить в ответе подробную информацию, включая разные способы решения проблемы, несомненно приветствуется. Только информация должна действительно напрямую относиться к вопросу.

Что касается 'i_cant_google', то это и вовсе не имеет значения. SO не преследует цели учить людей пользоваться поисковыми системами. Любой практически важный вопрос, на который еще нет ответа на SO, может быть задан и заслуживает ответов.